# Dataset of clinical trial accidents

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset of [clinical trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_trial) [accidents](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/01/what-we-know-so-far-about-clinical-trial-disaster-france), with ideally:

- drug tested
- phase of trial
- number of casualties, and description of injuries
- country

I am interested in both clinical trials of drugs and clinical trials of devices. I have mostly interested in human subjects.

Answer (score 1):

These are good starting points:

https://open.fda.gov

https://clinicaltrials.gov

http://www.data.gov 
(health section)

Hope this helps!